# megaraid sas resetting fusion adapter

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware-raid, lsi, megaraid

I'm running ESXi on a small home server and I'm seeing the following messages in ESXi logs:

lsi_mr3: fusionCompletionBHIntr:3558: Firmware in fault state.
WARNING: lsi_mr3: fusionReset:3918: megaraid_sas: resetting fusion adapter. mandateOCR flag 0x0

The virtual machines on the system are so far running fine, but from what I've searched online it seems that the raid controller has either failed or is likely to become faulty. When it says that "resetting fusion adapter", what does it mean? Is it being reinitialized? What is the meaning of mandateOCR?